# Compare two excel files (column) and merge rows from the two files as output

Tags: excel, excel-formula

File1.xls
1   NRS1    Open1   
2   NRS2    Open2   
3   NRS3    Open3   
4   NRS4    Open4   
5   NRS5    Open5

File2.xls
16  IP6 REI6    JO6 ZZ6 
27  IP7 REI7    JO7 ZZ7
3    IP3 REI3    JO3 ZZ3
2    IP2 REI2    JO2 ZZ2
1    IP1 REI1    JO1 ZZ1

I want to compare the first column from the 2 files and if the value from column A on file1 matches a value in column B on file2 then merge the matching rows from both files on the output:

New File: 
1   NRS1    Open1   1 IP1   REI1    JO1 ZZ1
2    NRS2    Open2   2 IP2   REI2    JO2 ZZ2
3    NRS3    Open3   3 IP3   REI3    JO3 ZZ3

Any way this is possible? Please and thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, it is possible by using formula as well as VBA. But what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks @Pankaj Jaju, I tried vlookup and it does the compare and output the values from the first file no problem. I just dont know how to return the correct values from the second file.    "=IF(VLOOKUP('C:\Excel Test\[File1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A1,'C:\Excel Test\[File2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$E,1,0),CONCATENATE('C:\Excel Test\[File1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A1,"|",'C:\Excel Test\[File1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B1,"|",'C:\Excel Test\[File1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C1),0)"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately my Excel app is not English, so I have difficulties testing English formulas. But replying to your comment below the original question, you can feed the result of [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function into [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd?CorrelationId=efb5d413-3348-4efb-a695-2b1174455c9c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) function to get dynamic references for the matched rows.

E.g.:

```
INDIRECT("[File2.xlsx]Sheet1!A" & MATCH([File2.xlsx]Sheet1!A1, [File1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A, 0))
```